# What are the differences between android 2.1 and android 2.2

Tags: 2.2-froyo, 2.1-eclair

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What advantages or new things have you found when upgrading from Android 2.1 to 2.2 ?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3201/what-advantages-or-new-things-have-you-found-when-upgrading-from-android-2-1-to-2)

I am going to buy an android phone now i have two choices either to buy a eclair(2.1) version or go for froyo(2.2) version, So i want to know what are the main new features that froyo have so i reject the eclair version phones?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.differencebetween.net/object/gadgets-object/difference-between-android-2-1-and-2-2/) article explains the differences nicely, and [this](http://gizmodo.com/5536751/android-22-vs-android-21-froyo-is-450-faster) one claims an incredible increase in speed. If you're a visual learner, [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dB-GGA15tm8) is always your best bet. But the general consensus is mainly centered around speed. Other perks include tethering, installation of apps to the SD card, and updated flash.

Comment: RE "updated flash": some 2.1 devices had Flash Lite, most didn't have anything.  So really the benefit of 2.2 is Flash, not updated Flash.

Comment: Flash lite is as useful as a white crayon